# How is the security / privacy in Azureus Vuze

Tags: privacy, torrent

I recently heard some people worrying about the privacy in Vuze. There are some rumors claiming that Vuze is not only malware infected, but also has a telemetry function to sell the users' information to third parties.

How is the security and privacy in Vuze really?
I am talking about an installation directly from the Azureus site.
And if it really has telemetry, how severe is the impact regarding spy functions?